# Cannot cancel nodes from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I am developing an app and I have a problem. I started recording GPS position, but data started to be too much. So I implemented a Button to cancel anything is under "Location" (or under "latitude" and "longitude", it is the same for me). The problem is that nothing seems to be canceled into the database.
I am facing this problem for 2 days and I am stuck. This is my DB:

[image: This is my database]

This is the code I used:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    private FragmentGalleryBinding binding;
    DatabaseReference mbase;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        galleryViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        EditText ET = binding.EditProva;
        Button btn = binding.buttonProva;
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mbase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatabaseReference drTest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                drTest.child("Location").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
                            dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Log.w("Errore DB: ", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        galleryViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                //textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
   }
```

Before this solution I used that code in the :

```
                DatabaseReference latRef = database.getReference("Location/latitude");
                latRef.removeValue();
                DatabaseReference longRef = database.getReference("Location/longitude");
                longRef.removeValue();
```

But neither does this work. I checked out other answers, but nothing helps me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly would you like to cancel? Do you need to remove the children within `Location` one by one?

Comment: I want to delete anything is under "Location". I prefer to delete them in one shot (see the other solution I reported in the end of the post), but considering that nothing was working I tried to delete them one by one. 
The code is a bit disordered because I am trying different ways.
Anyway, any solution that cancel data is ok

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.setValue(null)` operation to see if something is wrong?

Comment: I tried to debug the activity. It seems that that part of code is never called

Comment: Is any of onDataChange or onCancelled even called?

Comment: I implemented

                latRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        Log.e("OnDataChangeListener: ","mio mes");

                    }


and it is called.

Comment: As asked before, have you tried to attach a listener to the .setValue(null) operation to see if something is wrong?

Comment: I am not an expert programmer, sorry.
I implemented the OnComplete Listener and it is ok

Comment: WHat do you mean by "it's ok"?

Comment: the app goes in it and I read the Log I put. In code:
                        snapshot.getRef().setValue(null).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                            @Override

                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                Log.w("AAAOnComplete:", "Completato");

                            }

                        });

Comment: So the delete operation, completes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that nothing seems to be canceled into the database.

That's happening most likely because you are trying to delete a huge amount of data. If you want to remove everything that exists under the `Location` node, then you should consider deleting a reasonable number of items one at a time. That can be done on the client, but you can also write a function in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), to achieve the exact same result.